# Emojis in Tweets showing as "?" in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, emoji, tweets

Currently, I am collecting tweets based on emotions and doing the analysis. I have tweets with emojis but while collecting, it simply returns with a question mark.

For example:

Original tweet (in Twitter):

```
lipton ice tea
```

After collection (in MongoDB):

```
lipton ice tea?
```

I am using Twitter 4j Java package with MongoDB.

Comment: I'm guessing it's encoding problem somewhere in the pipeline

Comment: Where do you see the question mark? In the mongodb shell? Or when you retrieve it back for displaying on your page?

Comment: Also, "lipton" is capitalized. How did this happen?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev   I locally store all my tweets in JSON format, later stored in MongoDB. Before storing in MongoDB I used to check the information in JSON format using JSON viewer. In that, I found question mark instead of emoji. So, Its all before MongoDB function.

Comment: So perhaps your JSON viewer can't handle unicode emoji?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Think so, but I don't know how to solve this issue!!!

Comment: If it is the issue with JSON viewer, you don't need to do anything at all. If it is a problem with JSON however, that's your problem

Comment: Were you using robomongo? I'm using Robomongo and it shows `?` instead of the emoji, but inspecting the data in a viewer that supports UTF-8 it does display the emoji perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB uses UTF-8 by default so, unless you configured it *not* to, it is perfectly capable of storing the emojis.

This one time I spent a whole week banging my head against the wall because MongoDB wouldn't store Latin special characters. Turns out MongoDB worked just fine and it was Log4j the one that wasn't configured to print logs using UTF-8, so all I saw in the logs was `????` instead of `ñáçÜ`.

If you connect to your MongoDB instance using Mongo Shell (`<mongo installation dir>/bin/mongo.exe` in Windows), as I did, and query your data, you should be able to see the emojis. Here's a [quick reference for the Mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongo-shell/).

Your problem lies in your JSON visor, or in the encoding of the strings you're sending to MongoDB.

In Java, you might want to set the `file.encoding` system property to `UTF-8`, to make sure your program uses the right enconding when reading from files, input streams etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Robomongo, this is a robomongo problem.

Robomongo displays a `?` instead of emojis in table mode.